# Is there a reference for "Partial Object Assignment" inside the Object Initializer Syntax in C# ( Prop1 = { Prop2 = X })?

Tags: c#, constructor, object-initializers

Given the following 2 classes (VS 2015 + .Net 4.5) with fully mutable properties:

```
class Wrapped
{
    public int A {get; set;}
    public int B {get; set;}
}

class Wrapper
{
    public int X {get; set;}
    public Wrapped Y  {get; set;}
    public Wrapper()
    {
       Y = new Wrapped  { A = 5, B = 10 };
    }
}
```

I was intrigued to discover that Resharper 8.x recommended the usage of the Object Initializer Syntax (`UseObjectOrCollectionInitializer`) in the following nested initialization scenario, where I intended only a partial assignment of the wrapped entity - I wanted that the remainder of the `Wrapped` instance properties should retain any default values issued by the `Wrapper` class constructor:

```
// My Original code
var demo1 = new Wrapper
{
    X = 5
};
demo1.Y.B = 23;

// Resharper's refactoring suggestion
var demo2 = new Wrapper
{
    X = 5,
    Y = { B = 23 }
};
```

Initially, I assumed that the refactoring might be syntactic sugar for:

```
    new Wrapper
    {
        X = 5,
        Y = new Wrapped { B = 23 }
    };
```

Which is obviously *not* the same as my code, as it will wastefully construct and assign property `Y` twice (Once in `Wrapper's` default constructor and once in the assignment of `Y`, and worse, the setter it will lose any other property values assigned by `Wrapper's` constructor as it will assume any values assigned by `Wrapped`'s constructor.

However, upon IL disassembly with LinqPad I was amazed that Resharper was correct, viz that the initializer syntax:

```
Y = { B = 23 }
```

is equivalent to an explicit

```
demo1.Y.B = 23;
```

**So my question is** : Is there a formal reference for this "partial" (i.e. non-reconstructed) assignment syntax within the object intitialization syntax. I couldn't easily find one on MSDN, [e.g. Object and Collection Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), so I can weigh up the relative benefits and dangers of this syntax?

**Edit**

Also, noted that, just like the explicit syntax, that

```
Y = { B = 23 }
```

Will throw a `NullReferenceException` unless B is constructed inside of Y's constructor.

**IL Disassembly:**

i.e. both `demo1` and `demo2` result in this IL:

```
Wrapper..ctor
Wrapper.set_X
Wrapper.get_Y
Wrapped.set_B
```

Whereas demo3 results in the incorrect

```
Wrapper..ctor
Wrapper.set_X
Wrapped..ctor
Wrapped.set_B
Wrapper.set_Y
```

I've put a small sample showing the differences between 1&2, and 3 on [IdeOne here](https://ideone.com/Ykz2Pi)

Comment: I think I found a dupe with a suitable answer (giving a reference to a chapter in the C# spec). If not, feel free to reopen.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks - Found it - reference is 7.6.10.2 "nested object initializer". My bad.